JQuery code not displaying correct values into my chart
I'm stuck on something and would be very grateful if someone could please help me.
I'm building a simple chart/graph using HTML and JQuery.
I have the following code:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".graph-box .value").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).html()
    var iNum = parseInt(num);
    var eq= $(this).index(); 
    var finalSum = (iNum/1000);
    alert (finalSum);
    $(".graph-bar").width (finalSum + "%");
    });
    });
</script>

<style>
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
.graph-box {border:1px solid #ccc; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #ccc;}
.entry {display:flex;}
.name {width:500px; background-color:#ccc;}
.graph-bar {box-sizing:border-box; background-color:#ff0000; color:#fff; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border:1px solid blue; height:30px;}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="graph-box">     
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="name">England</div>
            <div class="value">817</div>
            <div class="graph"><div class="graph-bar color-1"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="name">Scotland</div>
            <div class="value">500</div>
            <div class="graph"><div class="graph-bar color-1"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="name">Wales</div>
            <div class="value">250</div>
            <div class="graph"><div class="graph-bar color-1"></div></div>
        </div>
</div>
        

As you can probably see, the JQuery checks the .value div and records the content. It then converts it into an integer. I know this part is correct and works as I put an alert in. When run, it gives me the 3 correct values.
What it is then supposed to do is to find the div called 'graph-bar' and set the width of that div according to the integer it created. However, when I run the code, all of the bars show the same width.
I've had this code running well when all of the integers are in one div, so I suspect this is something to do with the 'eq' code?
If someone could let me know how to fix this, and crucially why, I can know for the future and avoid this issue again.
Appreciate any help someone can give me!

Two things are missing from your solution:

You need to specify the width for the .graph class
.graph {width: 100%;}


You should update only the .graph-bar of the current parent node:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".graph-box .value").each(function(i, elem) {
        var num = $(this).html()
        var iNum = parseInt(num);
        var finalSum = (iNum/1000) * 100;
        $(elem).parent().find(".graph-bar").css("width", finalSum + "%");
        // Alternatively use the sibling function
        // $(elem).siblings().find(".graph-bar").css("width", finalSum + "%");
   });
});



You can find a working example in this JSFiddle.
